# Moving uploaded image to another server

Tags: php, curl

Hello Im trying to move an uploaded image to a remote server which works as a backup server. So the if I upload an image then it will automatic send the file to the backup server via curl.

The upload,rename and move image uploads perfectly but the only problem I got is to move copy the data to the remote server.

my upload/rename/move image function.

```
function imageUpload($dateiIn,$maxDateiGr,$maxDateix,$maxDateiy) {
    if($_FILES[$dateiIn]['size']>0) {
      if(checkUploadSize($_FILES[$dateiIn]['size'],$maxDateiGr)) {
        if($dateiEndung = imageCheckSize($_FILES[$dateiIn]['tmp_name'],$maxDateix,$maxDateiy)) {
          $md5datei = md5_file($_FILES[$dateiIn]['tmp_name']).'_'.rand(10000,99999);
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$dateiIn]['tmp_name'],'/var/www/thumbs/'.$md5datei.$dateiEndung)) { 


            return $md5datei.$dateiEndung;

          }
          else { return false; }
        }
        else { return false; }
      }
      else { return false; }
    }
    else { return false; }
  }
```

$md5datei = file name and $dateiEndung = the file format (jpg)

Now what I have tryed to do is the following:

```
  function imageUpload($dateiIn,$maxDateiGr,$maxDateix,$maxDateiy) {
    if($_FILES[$dateiIn]['size']>0) {
      if(checkUploadSize($_FILES[$dateiIn]['size'],$maxDateiGr)) {
        if($dateiEndung = imageCheckSize($_FILES[$dateiIn]['tmp_name'],$maxDateix,$maxDateiy)) {
          $md5datei = md5_file($_FILES[$dateiIn]['tmp_name']).'_'.rand(10000,99999);
          if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$dateiIn]['tmp_name'],'/var/www/thumbs/'.$md5datei.$dateiEndung)) { 


            $filename = '/var/www/thumbs/'.$md5datei.$dateiEndung;
            $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
            $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
            $POST_DATA   = array('file'=>base64_encode($data));
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://external.net/upload.php');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close ($curl);

// return name to be able to write it inside the database
            return $md5datei.$dateiEndung;

          }
          else { return false; }
        }
        else { return false; }
      }
      else { return false; }
    }
    else { return false; }
  }
```

And on the external.net server I got the upload.php file:

```
<?PHP
$encoded_file=$_POST['file'];
$decoded_file=base64_decode($encoded_file);
$dest = "/var/www/thumbs/".$decoded_file;
/*Now you can copy the uploaded file to your server.*/
file_put_contents($dest,$decoded_file);
?>
```

But the file still don't land inside the /var/www/thumbs folder on the external server.

And both error logs are empty and I don't know anymore what to do without an error..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about we change

```
$POST_DATA   = array('file'=>base64_encode($data),'FILENAME'=>$filename);
```

and in `upload.php`

```
$dest = "/var/www/thumbs/".$decoded_file;
```

to

```
$dest = "/var/www/thumbs/".$_POST['FILENAME'];
```

and then run the code

Comment: $dest = "/var/www/thumbs/".$_POST['FILENAME']; to $dest = $_POST['FILENAME']; and now it works.